# Error in function after moving code

Tags: node.js

When I move the function 'send()' within this function, the code stops working.

I didn't get any errors, the program just became unresponsive. I have no idea why and it took me an half hour to figure out how to solve the problem. I'd like to know what this caused and how to prevent it in the future.

Thanks in advance.

Working code:

```
function warn(channelID, userID, reason){
    if(!userExists(channelID, userID)) return;
    var warnings = players[userID].warnings;

    var today = new Date().getTime();
    var active = 0;
    for (key in warnings){
        date = warnings[key].date;
        if(today - date < 60*1000){
            active++;
        }
    }

    if (active >= 3){
        kick(channelID, userID, "You have been automatically kicked after 3 (active) warnings.");
        log("Bot", userID, "kick", "3 warnings");
    }

    send(channelID, reason); //this function
}
```

Code stopped working after moving the 'send()' function:

```
function warn(channelID, userID, reason){
    if(!userExists(channelID, userID)) return;
    var warnings = players[userID].warnings;

    var today = new Date().getTime();
    var active = 0;
    for (key in warnings){
        date = warnings[key].date;
        if(today - date < 60*1000){
            active++;
        }
    }

    send(channelID, reason); //this function

    if (active >= 3){
        kick(channelID, userID, "You have been automatically kicked after 3 (active) warnings.");
        log("Bot", userID, "kick", "3 warnings");
    }
}
```

The code started working again after I added 'return;' add the end of the function.

```
function warn(channelID, userID, reason){
    if(!userExists(channelID, userID)) return;
    var warnings = players[userID].warnings;

    var today = new Date().getTime();
    var active = 0;
    for (key in warnings){
        date = warnings[key].date;
        if(today - date < 60*1000){
            active++;
        }
    }

    send(channelID, reason);

    if (active >= 3){
        kick(channelID, userID, "You have been automatically kicked after 3 (active) warnings.");
        log("Bot", userID, "kick", "3 warnings");
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: There is no execution difference between the last two scenarios, so something else besides the addition of the `return` statement is affecting things.  I'm wondering if you have some intermittent timing problem.  Are either `send()` `or kick()` asynchronous?

Comment: Are either `channelID` or `userID` objects that might get modified by either `send()` or by `kick()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 The weird thing is that just adding the `return` statement solved the problem. And `channelID` and `userID` never get modified inside this function, neither in `send()` or `kick()`

Comment: Are you transpiling your code?  Adding a `return` all by itself does not change the execution of the code you show.  But if you were transpiling, it could change the way the code was transpiled in some odd sort of way.  If you're not transpliing, then I really think you need to look elsewhere because falling through the end of a Javascript function with no `return` at the end is exactly the same outcome as adding a `return` at the end.  Exactly the same.  So something else is causing your problem.